# How to use Tregex on not English texts with StanfordCoreNLP Server?

Tags: parsing, nlp

I am trying to use Tregex with StanfordCoreNLP Server for processing french texts. The server is configured with french properties, but the /tregex endpoint seems to process the text automatically with english parsing.

However when I am trying to parse the text with the regular parser, everything works pretty well and the french parser is correctly applied.

Here is an example:

**Input Sentence**

> Pierre et Jean sont dans la cuisine

**Regular Parsing :**

`http://localhost:8082/?properties=outputFormat&properties=depparse.model+%3D+edu%2Fstanford%2Fnlp%2Fmodels%2Fparser%2Fnndep%2FUD_French.gzpos.model&properties=parse.model&properties=tokenize.language&prop
erties=depparse.language&properties=annotators`

> (ROOT
>    (SENT
>      (NP (NPP Pierre)
>        (COORD (CC et)
>          (NP (NPP Jean))))
>      (VN (V sont))
>      (PP (P dans)
>        (NP (DET la) (NC cuisine)))))

**Tregex Parsing**

`http://localhost:8082/tregex?properties=annotators&properties=outputFormat&properties=depparse.model+%3D+edu%2Fstanford%2Fnlp%2Fmodels%2Fparser%2Fnndep%2FUD_French.gzpos.model&properties=parse.model&properties=tokenize.language&properties=depparse.language&pattern=NP%3Dnoun1+%24+NP%3Dnoun2`

> {
>    "sentences": [
>      {
>        "0": {
>          "match": "(NP (NNP Pierre)\n  (CC et)\n  (NNP Jean))\n",
>          "namedNodes": [
>            {
>              "noun1": "(NP (NNP Pierre)\n  (CC et)\n  (NNP Jean))\n"
>   <          },
>            {
>              "noun2": "(NP\n  (NP (JJ sont) (NNS dans))\n  (PP (FW la)\n    >(NP (NN cuisine))))\n"
>            }
>          ]
>        },
>        "1": {
>          "match": "(NP\n  (NP (JJ sont) (NNS dans))\n  (PP (FW la)\n    (NP >(NN cuisine))))\n",
>          "namedNodes": [
>            {
>              "noun1": "(NP\n  (NP (JJ sont) (NNS dans))\n  (PP (FW la)\n    >(NP (NN cuisine))))\n"
>           },
>            {
>              "noun2": "(NP (NNP Pierre)\n  (CC et)\n  (NNP Jean))\n"
>            }
>          ]
>        }
>      }
>    ]
>   }

As you can see, the parsing is not the same in both cases.

After a quick check into the server logs, I noticed that the annotators are automatically discarded and replaced by the default english models :

```
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool - Replacing old annotator "coref" with signature [coref.language:fr;coref.mode:statistical;] with new annotator with signature []
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool - Replacing old annotator "ssplit" with signature [tokenize.language:fr;] with new annotator with signature []
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool - Replacing old annotator "depparse" with signature [depparse.language:french;depparse.model:edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_French.gz;] with new annotator with signature []
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool - Replacing old annotator "tokenize" with signature [tokenize.language:fr;] with new annotator with signature []
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool - Replacing old annotator "mention" with signature [mention.type:dep;coref.language:fr;coref.mode:statistical;] with new annotator with signature []
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool - Replacing old annotator "pos" with signature [pos.model:edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/french/french.tagger;] with new annotator with signature []
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool - Replacing old annotator "openie" with signature [openie.strip_entailments:true;] with new annotator with signature []
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool - Replacing old annotator "parse" with signature [parse.model:edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz;parse.binaryTrees:true;] with new annotator with signature []
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[pool-2-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.2 sec].
```

I tried the same example on the CoreNLP test server (http://corenlp.run/) and it works perfectly.

I suppose I am doing something wrong with the server configuration but I don't know what :)

Many thanks for your help!

Louis

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is what I have find out : we can see in [the code](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/e5b2842a5a5243486d5b23fc91e31c955e7d60a2/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLPServer.java) used by Stanford Core NLP that it doesn't take in account parameters but uses default values (line 1090). They have fixed it on github, that is why [the corenlp server](http://corenlp.run/) doesn't encounter this problem anymore and the 3.9.0 version should be OK.

Hopefully it helps